# How to swap monitor positions when using an extended monitor?

Tags: windows-7, extended-desktop

I'm using an extended monitor. Currently, when viewing the display monitors in the OS, I see they are listed as below.

> `1` `2`

My problem is that my extended monitor is not on my right hand-side as it says - i.e. physically I place it on the left. What I want is to change the posistions listed in the OS to be

> `2` `1`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Wow... It's so naive of me. After posting the question, I try dragging the monitor `2` and drop it on the left of monitor `1` and everything is right what I expect.

So simply, use drag 'n' drop to deal with the mornitor positions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't feel bad - I have a lot of customers who can't get it in their heads that it doesn't matter if the numbers are in order or not, as long as they're CORRECT.  It's only intuitive once you realize what it's representing.

Comment: I added some pictures for ya for others to see.

Comment: @Shinrai That's an excellent point. If the order isn't important, using something as inherently ordered as numbers focuses the users on the wrong thing. If I have to write something like this, I'm going to use pictures of kittens.

Comment: @Spike - One of the few things I've ever liked about Catalyst Control Center is the way it handles arranging monitors in Eyefinity display groups.  Instead of numbering them, it turns them blue one at a time and asks you to click the corresponding part of the thumbnail.

Comment: Talk about non-obvious.  Why do people make *everything* into some stupid video game, where it is "guess if this is an icon, guess what actions you can apply, and what the actions might do".

Comment: I *never* knew you could click and drag those screens, and I've been working with extended displays for years! Now I can finally have my monitor on the left of my laptop. :)

Comment: @IraBaxter it's called hidden [affordance](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/24/affordance-most-underrated-word-in-web-design/)! Thanks for the answer Nam G VU I  would never have worked that out myself!

Comment: I was not aware at all that we can actually drag them thanks a bunch it helped me

Comment: It wasn't obvious at all, how is someone supposed to know the interface can do that? When you use atypical user interfaces this tends to confuse people.